# Service inside container not receiving requests

Tags: python-3.x, docker, flask, connexion

I am running a container with :

```
docker run --env-file .env <container_id> -p 0.0.0.0:8080:8080
```

The service inside the container is a python flask service, built with the library [connexion](https://connexion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), and listening on 0.0.0.0:8080.

When I `docker ls`, the column PORTS shows `8080/tcp`, and I am not able to request the service, eg from swagger.

How can I request the service successfully ? Is `8080/tcp` in the PORTS column means that my container is not bind to any port on the host machine ?

Comment: Docker options like `-p` need to go _before_ the image name.  If it's _after_ the image name it will be interpreted as the command to run.

Comment: that was it thx !